# How Do I Debug My Android Apps on a Wileyfox Swift?

Tags: android

I tried the usual tap-seven-times-on-the-build-number process to get a Wileyfox Swift recognized by my Ubuntu machine for debugging. While I could get into developer options and enable debugging, I didn't get the MAC address authorization dialog, and `adb devices` said `no permissions`.

What's the magic trick to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This blog post](http://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/using-adb-with-wileyfox-swift) advises adding `0x2970` on a line to the end of `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`, plus stopping and restarting `adb`. Apparently, that helped the author of that post, but it proved to be insufficient for me.

I also had to add a line to the end of my `udev` rules for Android devices (which I set up as `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`, 'cause I got a whole lot of 'em).:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2970", ATTR{idProduct}=="2282", MODE="0666"
```

That, plus `sudo service udev restart`, brought up the authorization dialog when I plugged in the Swift, `adb` recognizes the device, Android Studio can run apps on it, and the cherubim and seraphim sang "Hallelujah!".

<sub>Actually, that last bit didn't happen, but it could have. Really.</sub>

<sub><sub>No actual cherubim or seraphim were harmed in the creation of this answer</sub></sub>